# Setting title to custom view for status item cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, statusbar, nsstatusitem

I've  have custom status view which i have set to status item view property.

```
- (id)initWithStatusItem:(NSStatusItem *)statusItem
{
    CGFloat itemWidth = [statusItem length];
    CGFloat itemHeight = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] thickness];
    NSRect itemRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, itemWidth, itemHeight);
    self = [super initWithFrame:itemRect];

    //isReachable = YES;
    if (self != nil) {
        _statusItem = statusItem;
        _statusItem.view = self;

        [self checkReachability];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{

    NSColor *tintColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    tintColor = (!_isReachable)?[NSColor grayColor]:(self.isHighlighted?[NSColor whiteColor]:([self isDarkStyle]?[NSColor whiteColor]:[NSColor blackColor]));

    self.image = [[NSImage imageNamed:@"icn_statusitem"] imageTintedWithColor:tintColor];

    [self.statusItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:dirtyRect withHighlight:self.isHighlighted];

    NSImage *icon = self.image;
    NSSize iconSize = [icon size];
    NSRect bounds = self.bounds;
    CGFloat iconX = roundf((NSWidth(bounds) - iconSize.width) / 2);
    CGFloat iconY = roundf((NSHeight(bounds) - iconSize.height) / 2);
    NSPoint iconPoint = NSMakePoint(iconX, iconY);

    [icon drawAtPoint:iconPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

    //[self checkReachability];
}
```

I have initialized here the status bar when it launchs presents the icon in status item.
after receving notification `statusSpeedNotification` i want change status item image to string.
 i have tried this its not working

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // Install status item into the menu bar
        statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];
        _statusItemView = [[StatusItemView alloc] initWithStatusItem:statusItem];
        _statusItemView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icn_statusitem"];
        _statusItemView.alternateImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icn_statusitem"];
        _statusItemView.action = @selector(togglePanel:);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"statusSpeedNotification" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
            NSString *speed = note.userInfo[@"speed"];
            _statusItemView.image= nil;
            _statusItemView.alternateImage = nil;
              statusItem.button.title = speed;

        }];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Any suggestions would be more helpful.

Comment: The target/action API of `NSStatusItem` and `drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect` is deprecated. It's highly recommended to use the `button` property. It's easier to use and it supports dark mode by default.

Comment: Yes but this is pretty old project so i need to do in this way it is in live as new requiretiment i need to change status item icon to text  and text to icon occasionally in app.

Comment: Your observer, which changes the button's title, may be run on a background thread.  In general, UI changes should be performed on the main thread.